# Black screen on login, can get thru decrypt disk and access command line but no GUI

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, encryption, alternate

Running 12.04 64 bit fresh alternative install, with disk crypto on a new Lenovo laptop

Install didn't connect and install modules, even though I had the network cable plugged in and don't have any whacky proxy settings. I had to manually install ubuntu-desktop and define sources after initial installation, so this seemed a bit weird (ISO matched MD5 sum though)

I unplug the network cable, otherwise I get a black screen that I can do nothing with.
So I turn laptop on, I have disk encryption, I type in the password at the Ubuntu decryption GUI then get "set up successfully" message
"Waiting for network configuration ..." then "Waiting for up to 60 more seconds for network configuration"
At this stage (a) If I wait for it then I get a black screen that I can do nothing with. (b) If I interrupt the process by pressing escape, then I break through to the command line.
From the command line, I can go ahead and login, then plug my network cable in to do apt-get commands.

As a precaution I do some house keeping which takes a few mins to run:

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get upgrade

Running startx to get to the GUI gives:

> Fatal server errror:
>   no screens found

The .Xauthority file is being created in my home directory but it's empty.

I review my order and note the system graphics:
Intel HD Graphics (WWAN or mSATA capable)

So it's weird that I can't get to the Gnome. It looks like drivers aren't working. Is there a way of getting Intel drivers from the command line? Or do you have any other suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: You can install drivers using apt-get. I do not know what's the name of intel driver package. Maybe someone else will be able to tell you more about it. Also, I would advise you to try with the default .iso

Answer (score 1):

I run the command below and it mentions VGA compatible controller: Intel Corp. So I didn't think it's a driver issue:

```
lspci
```

But then when running startx, error message mentions a log file:

```
/var/log/Xog.0.log
```

Log file mentions:

- "Warning, couldn't open module intel"
- "Failed to load module "intel""
- I get the same message for vesa, fbdev,

Running startx mentions Wiki [page](http://wiki.x.org) but it wasn't very helpful (few / no results).

FTW: Install Intel [drivers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11580721)

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I had to do a restart and be patient after logging-in, now I'm in business.